# Ubuntu Software not loading categories

Tags: software-center, 19.04

I've tried the following:

- sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-software
- sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade

Running on Ubuntu 19.04 and tried with Pi-hole disabled.

[image: screenshot]

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a fix:

```
sudo apt autoremove gnome-software && sudo apt install gnome-software
```

Comment: This did not work for me on 21.04

Answer (score 5):

As my snap store app was apparently hanging and the search function was not working properly, I decided to install gnome-store in my ubuntu 20.04 and removed the snap store. However, I later changed my mind and decided to re-install the snap store. But to my surprise, it was showing a snap store, not ubuntu software. The steps I followed to reclaim the old ubuntu software (snap store) are:

1. Completely removed and purged gnome-software using `sudo apt purge gnome-software`
2. Then removed the snap-store using `snap remove snap-store`
3. Then re-installed snap store using `snap install snap-store`
4. To regain the standard ubuntu icon, use the following command:-
   `snap refresh snap-store --channel=stable/ubuntu-20.04`

This fixes the issue !!

Comment: This did not work for me on 21.04

Comment: What exactly happened

Comment: Can you tell me

Comment: Nothing. All commands executed fine. But the Software app still shows just 7 'editor's pick apps' only. Any category I choose is empty with just one box with three dots showing for each category.

Comment: Oh so it's working. After it shows 3 dot box, just have patience. It's loading

Comment: @charlie don't worry just have a strong internet connection and wait

Comment: @simran...I have a strong enough connection to live stream across multiple devices simultaneously...But it indeed takes an exceptionally long time for the apps to load... However, at long last, they do popup. Thanks!

Comment: You're most welcome. And yeah that is how it works. No other way. It does take long. That's why you should never rely on store and instead go for synaptics or command line. Snap store apps are less stable and less reliable in general

Comment: @charlie did you get it

Comment: Worked on 22.04. Just changed the version in step 4.

Answer (score 1):

For me, ending the process and re-opening solved the error.

1. Open System Monitor and search for 'snap-store' process.
2. Select the snap-store process and click 'End Process'.
3. Re-open Ubuntu Software

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 20.04 has segregated the software manager into 2 categories:

1. Ubuntu Software
2. Software (I think this is what you're looking for. Please search for 'Software' and add to favorites).

Took me a while figure out but then my eyes zeroed in on 'Software' in Application catalogue.

Cheers!