# Problem with snap on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, snap

I would like you to help me with the following problem when installing snaps applications in Ubuntu 20.04, it gives me an error and gives me the following message

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No necesita ser "root" para instalar un Snap.

```
sudo snap install chromium
```

Ingrese su contraseña cuando se le solicite y se instalará Chromium

---

You do not need to be "root" to install a Snap.

```
sudo snap install chromium
```

Enter your password when asked, and Chromium will be installed

Comment: Sigue dando el mismo error. Cuando recien se lanzo el SO lo instale para probarlo y nunca me dio ese error sino hasta ahora

Answer (score 0):

Close the terminal. Search for Chromium in the Software app. Click on the circular blue Chromium icon to bring up the Chromium page, and click the green Install button to install it. You will be asked to authenticate with your user password in order to install Chromium.

If that doesn't work open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update # refresh list of available software
sudo snap install chromium
```

If the Software app still isn't loading packages after running `sudo apt update`, please read the answers to [Ubuntu Software not loading categories](https://askubuntu.com/q/1152322/). Please read the two suggested commands that the author of that question already tried too.

Comment: cuando abro la tienda no me aparecen ninguna de las aplicaciones